# OpenERP - modifying database port setting and saving the configuration file

Tags: odoo

I want to change database port from 5432 to 5433, for OpenERP Server. When I try to edit openerp-server.conf file or config.py file, they cannot be saved, error said the file is opened by another program. I stopped openerp-server service but still cannot save the file. I am using OpenERP v6.

My question is am I looking to the right files to change database listening port? If yes how I can save the edited files? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The files could be right or not. That depends on how openerp is started. What OS are you using ? How do you start openerp ?

Comment: @PeterMmm   OS is Windows 7 Professional. Service openerp-server-6.0 has Startup Type Automatic.

Comment: I don't know OERP on Windows very well. The server log normally prints out what config is used. Search for open*.log or similiar on your system. To get the process that locks the files look here: http://superuser.com/questions/117902/easy-way-to-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows

Comment: @PeterMmm I have downloaded Process Explorer but it does not show any processes that might block openerp-server.conf file. Searched the log file. It only indicates the server settings but does not say from which file they come from.

Comment: Change service settings to start manual. Reboot. Try to edit the config file and start service manually.

Comment: @PeterMmm Just did it. The file still cannot be saved.

Comment: @PeterMmm I have copied file to desktop then managed to delete the file at original location. Changed the desktop version of file and then copied back. It worked. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The correct file for openerp-server setting is openerp-server.conf.

I have copied file to desktop then managed to delete the file at original location. Changed the desktop version of file and then copied back. It worked.